# How to save annoations on map View

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I want to save the added annotations on the map view.
I am adding annotation on current position of the device and when user opens the app later all the added annotations should be there on map view.
How can i do this please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to create a dictionary and store all the annotation in that dictionary. Later save the dictionary in NSUserDefaults.

The other way is to make a core data database and store the key values (For MKAnnotation: title, subtitle, latitude, longitude in their primitive data types.) in the database. Later when loading create all the annotation and put them in the map.

You need to know how to use CoreData, and its different versions. And some idea on MapKit. To show the annotations, you have to create MKAnnotation after loading the data (title, subtitle, latitude, longitude) from core data. That's the easiest way.

You can store objects in core data. But in that case you need to subclass MKAnnotation class to make it serializable, I guess.

Comment: How to store the key values in the database? i am storing latitude and longitude values right now.please guide with some sample code i am newbie it will be a great help.Thank you very much for the quick reply.

Comment: In the database, key values -> important values :) For MKAnnotation: title, subtitle, latitude, longitude in their primitive data types.

Comment: What kind of sample code you are looking for? For core data or for NSDictionary?

Comment: for core data..i am storing latitude and longitude values in core data table.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials available on how use core data. Just google!